# Updating a string

Tags: java, eclipse, string, operation

I already opened a similar question, unfortunetly I didnt explain my problem correctly, sorry about that. 
This time I hope  everyone understand what I mean.
My intention is to Update a String A with a String B.
For example:

```
String A: 
A 
B 
C//Good morning, sir 
D//A comment 
E


String B: 
A 
B//Yes 
C 
D 
DD 
E

The result should be: 
A 
B//Yes 
C//Good morning, sir 
D//A comment 
DD 
E
```

I do not know where the differences are, I just want to keep everything in String A and just add the new things from String B (to the correct positions).
Has anyone an idea if java can do this?

Comment: Fix your other question rather than opening a new one.

Comment: You should modify your original question, not post a new one. Also this seems to have received several answers in your other question.

Comment: that went over my head.. what kind of string is this

Answer (score 0):

Well, how do you know where to insert the parts of your string? You could use an array and update write all words of your strings on an index by using a simple loop.